# How to identify which app is creating user credentials in the security settings?

Tags: security, settings, certificates

I was going through my Android device settings and found "rsa key" stored in user credentials. There, it says the "rsa key" is for VPN and apps. But I don't use any VPN.

How to identify which app is creating user credentials in the security settings?

Comment: Sorry but how should we know if a certificate (with private key) that you don't describe or even present us the name is used or required by your apps which we again don't know anything about.

Comment: I don't have any private certificate installed. I have checked there are only system certificates